# CodeIgniter: show different nav menu per user type

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have searched everywhere here about showing different nav menu depends on user type. My database user table has a field named "user_type". Below is the flow on what i have in mind. The problem is I don't know how to execute it.

```
if($user_type == 'Admin') {
$this->load->view('navbar-menu');
} else if($user_type == 'Client') {
$this->load->view('navbar-menu-client');
} else {
$this->load->view('navbar-menu-normal');
}
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly? I see you have the idea for what you want to do... Just try to do it. Don't expect others do your job. Then if you find a trouble ask it (precisely)... but don't ask before to do the work.

Comment: The problem is i don't know how to execute it. (i just edit my question, thanks)

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: I can't distinguish if the user logged in is admin or client

Comment: put the user_type in session and filter  according to it

Answer (score 0):

```
also make a session code for it and pass this user_ID and compare in your database and get the user_type in your table.
i have make simple code for your .
make a condtoller in your folder with (My_controller.php) this name and than after go yo your browser and run this URL : HOSTNAME/index.php/My_controller/index

<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function my_controller()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $where = array('user_ID' => $this->session->userdata['login_ID']);
        $user_type = $this->yourmodelname->yourfunctioname($where);
        if($user_type == 'Admin') 
        {
            $this->load->view('navbar-menu');
        }
        else if($user_type == 'Client') 
        {
            $this->load->view('navbar-menu-client');
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->load->view('navbar-menu-normal');
        }
    }
}
?>
```